# What is the maximum column varchar size for Primary columns in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle19c

I am trying to create a column with varchar(4000) and creating a primary key on it, is throwing error. While when I am trying to create a column with varchar(1599) and adding a primary key on it, it works fine.

So a does that mean the max size of the primary column in oracle is varchar(1599) ?

Oracle version => 19.16.0.0.0

I am trying like:

```
CREATE TABLE table( PK1_name varchar(4000 char) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL);
```

Comment: Sorry but "throwing error" is as useful as "fix error". The error message is important, it explains what's wrong.

Comment: What does the documentation say? https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/23/lnpcb/datatypes-and-host-variables.html

Comment: I've just created primary key on a VARCHAR2(4000) column, no problem. Though, that most probably wouldn't be my first choice for a primary key column, but - yes, you can do it, if you do it properly.

Comment: I am getting this error:  
ORA-01450: maximum key length (6398) exceeded
01450. 00000 -  "maximum key length (%s) exceeded"
*Cause:    
*Action:

Comment: `varchar2` is hard-limited by **bytes**, not by number of characters. For multibyte database codepage it will be less that 4k (32k), which is [clearly described in the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/Data-Types.html#GUID-0DC7FFAA-F03F-4448-8487-F2592496A510): *While size may be expressed in bytes or characters (code points) the independent absolute maximum length of any character value that can be stored into a VARCHAR2 column is 32767 or 4000 bytes, depending on MAX_STRING_SIZE*

Comment: Do we have similar restriction while creating primaryKey contrain. Because I am trying something like below and getting same exception.

CREATE TABLE test1( col1 varchar(4000) NOT NULL, col2 varchar(4000) NOT NULL, 
col3 varchar(4000), col4 varchar(4000), col5 varchar(4000) NOT NULL, col6 varchar(4000),
col7 varchar(4000) ,  PRIMARY KEY(col1, col2, col3));

Answer (score 3):

> **ORA-01450**: maximum key length (string) exceeded
>
> **Cause**: The combined length of all the columns specified in a CREATE
> INDEX statement exceeded the maximum index length. The maximum index
> length varies by operating system.
>
> The total index length is computed as the sum of the width of all
> indexed columns plus the number of indexed columns.
>
> Date fields have a length of 7, character fields have their defined
> length, and numeric fields have a length of 22. Numeric length =
> (precision/2) + 1. If negative, add +1.
>
> **Action:** Select columns to be indexed so the total index length does
> not exceed the maximum index length for the operating system.
>
> See also your operating system-specific Oracle documentation.

In **my** database it works:

```
SQL> CREATE TABLE test ( PK1_name varchar(4000 char) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL);

Table created.

SQL>
```

Though, note that code you posted is invalid (table name can't be `table`). Also, primary keys don't allow nulls anyway, so there's no use in specifying that column to be `not null`. Finally, Oracle recommends we use `varchar2` datatype instead of `varchar`.

---

As I commented, choosing `varchar2(4000)` column as a primary key is rarely a good idea; Oracle's optimizer might choose to use full table scan instead of using such a long index. I'd suggest you to abandon this idea and create another column for a primary key; as you're on 19c, one option is to use an **identity** column, so you'd then

```
SQL> create table test2
  2    (id        number generated always as identity primary key,
  3     name      varchar2(4000)
  4    );

Table created.

SQL>
```

---

**[EDIT]**

As of your comment: this is what happens in my database:

```
SQL> CREATE TABLE test1
  2  (
  3     col1   VARCHAR (4000) NOT NULL,
  4     col2   VARCHAR (4000) NOT NULL,
  5     col3   VARCHAR (4000),
  6     col4   VARCHAR (4000),
  7     col5   VARCHAR (4000) NOT NULL,
  8     col6   VARCHAR (4000),
  9     col7   VARCHAR (4000),
 10     PRIMARY KEY (col1, col2, col3)
 11  );
CREATE TABLE test1
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01450: maximum key length (6398) exceeded


SQL>
```

But, once again: when I see bunch of VARCHAR2(**4000**) columns and one - or a few of them - making a primary key, that smells like bad, Bad, BAD data model. Reconsider what you're doing.

Comment: Do we have similar restriction while creating primaryKey contrain. Because I am trying something like below and getting same exception. CREATE TABLE test1( col1 varchar(4000) NOT NULL, col2 varchar(4000) NOT NULL, col3 varchar(4000), col4 varchar(4000), col5 varchar(4000) NOT NULL, col6 varchar(4000), col7 varchar(4000) , PRIMARY KEY(col1, col2, col3))